# Working with a large string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I am working with the following string:

```
"I know an old lady who swallowed a fly.
I don't know why she swallowed the fly. Perhaps she'll die.

I know an old lady who swallowed a spider.
It wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her."
```

I am trying to split them up based on new lines and extra space into an array, and trying regex has not worked, any recommendations?

```
["I know an old lady who swallowed a fly", "I don't know why she swallowed the fly. Perhaps she'll die.","I know an old lady who swallowed a spider.", "It wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her."]
```

Comment: Can you provide the regular expression that you have tried? Also, where is this string coming from, user-input, `textarea` object, `File` object?

Comment: Looks like a split using `\n+` should do the job. What did you try?

Comment: I tried using .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm," ") and .replace(/(\n+)/gm," ")

Comment: String is just placed in the code as a local var.

Comment: Is it is also that I cannot save the variable with line breaks?

Comment: try `string.split(/[\n\r]+/)`

Comment: If you have the separate lines in an array, what you want to do is **join** them, not split them. You can use `.join("\n")` to do that. Now, if you then add the string to a page as HTML text, the browser will ignore the newlines unless you've got appropriate CSS to control that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like this with the global and multiline flags:

```
/$/gm;
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV2kH1/1)**

```
string.split(/$/gm)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that end up with the newlines be part of the result?

Comment: @Bergi it is used to split the string